# c++ override the >> operator for Array Class

Tags: c++, arrays, overriding, istream

I'm trying to override the >> operator for my own Array Class:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Array& array) {
for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
    input >> array[i];

return input;
}
```

But i become the following Error:

> std::istream& Array::operator>>(std::istream&, const Array&)'
>   must take exactly one argument

All the examples that I've seen, are implemented like it. I don't know, why the compiler want excacty one argument?
What have I to do?

Comment: It's different when you implement it from outside the class or from inside of it. If you're inside the Array class you need one parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `operator>>` is a member of the class, it will operate on an `Array` object and take what parameter you give it:

```
Array a;
a >> whatever;
```

You seem to want an `istream` to write into it, which means it's not a member, so either move it outside the class, or declare it as `friend` (which effectively makes it a non-member):

```
class Array
{
//.........
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Array& array) {
   for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
      input >> array[i];

   return input;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When defined inside the class, binary operator functions should have only one argument (because the left-hand argument is implicitly `*this`). You have to define the extractor as a free function, which you can do by defining it outside the class. Also, if the extractor needs to access private variables, you can define/declare it as a `friend` inside the class.